# создание итератора для кастомного класса

Tags: java, ооп

Пытаюсь создать итератор для кастомного класса в java.У меня есть класс  FullName

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class FullName {
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public FullName(String surname, String name, int age) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    public void printFullName(){
        System.out.println("name: " + name + " surname: " + surname + " age: " + age);

    }
}
```

и класс,который хранит массив таких структур: FullNameCollections

```
public class FullNameCollections  {
    private static FullName [] arrFullname;
    public FullNameCollections(String[] name){
        arrFullname = new FullName[name.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
            FullName tmp = new FullName("mr " + name[i], name[i],(int)(1 + Math.random()*100));
            arrFullname[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    public int getSize(){
        return arrFullname.length;
    }
    public static FullName[] getArr(){
        return arrFullname;
    }

    public FullNameIterator iterator() {

        return new FullNameIterator(this);
    }
}


public class FullNameIterator implements Iterator<FullNameCollections> {

    private FullNameCollections fullNameCollections;
    private int indexEl;

    public FullNameIterator(FullNameCollections fullNameCollections) {
        this.fullNameCollections = fullNameCollections;
        indexEl = fullNameCollections.getSize();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (indexEl >= 0) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public FullNameCollections next(){
        FullName[] tmp = FullNameCollections.getArr();
        indexEl--;
        return (FullNameCollections)tmp[indexEl];
    }

}
```

В его конструкторе создаю массив структур(класса FullName). Создал класс итератора для работа с этой коллекцией.Но метод next я не могу определить так,что бы он возвращал объект класса FullName,который я мог бы вывести на консоль во внешнем коде через метод print
То есть, я хочу:

```
 String [] str = {"Вася","Даша","Даша"};
        FullNameCollections fullNameCollections = new FullNameCollections(str);
        Iterator iter = fullNameCollections.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FullName fullName = iter.next();
            fullName.printFullName();
        }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать,ибо возвращаемый тип данных в методе next() может быть только FullNameCollections

Comment: Если предоставленный ответ вас устраивает, то могли бы вы, пожалуйста, его отметить как "решение вопроса" (галочкой), чтобы вопрос не попадал в список не отвеченных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пример реализации:**

```
public class FullNameCollections implements Iterable<FullName> {
    private final FullName[] array;

    public FullNameCollections(String[] name) {
        array = new FullName[name.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            array[i] = new FullName("mr " + name[i], name[i], new Random().nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<FullName> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<FullName>() {
            private int index;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < array.length;
            }

            @Override
            public FullName next() {
                return array[index++];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Пример использования:**

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"123", "456", "789"};
        // конструкция for each, на самом деле (при компиляции), разворачиватеся в итератор
        for (FullName fullName : new FullNameCollections(strings)) {
            fullName.printFullName();
        }
    }
}
```