# Итерируемый класс-контейнер

Tags: java

Есть следующий код который выводит результат следующим образом: в одной строке текст с двумя пробелами между буквами, в следующей строке под каждой буквой ее номер.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class String1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String str1 = "";
        
        try (Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            str1 = sc1.nextLine();  
        }
        lat(str1);  
    }
    private static void lat(String str1) {
        String codeString = "";
        String formattedString = "";
        
        for (char ch : str1.toCharArray()) {
     codeString += Character.isAlphabetic(ch) ? String.format("%-3s", ch - 'a' + 1) : ch;
     formattedString += Character.isAlphabetic(ch) ? String.format("%-3s", ch) : ch;
        }
        System.out.println(formattedString);
        System.out.println(codeString);
    }

}
```

Пример вывода:

```
i  d  k   w  h  o   u  
9  4  11  23 8  15  21
```

А теперь нужен итерируемый класс-контейнер для сохранения данных в виде массива строк.
И проблема в том что я не могу понять, как реализовать этот итерируемый класс-контейнер, так ещё и в виде массива строк.
Вот вроде итератор, должен же выглядеть как-то так?

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    public boolean hasNext();
    public String next();
    public void remove();
}
```

А в класс-контейнере тогда как объявлять? И как сделать массив строк?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант :

- Поместить данные в коллекцию.
- Использовать [iterator()](https://javatpoint.com/java-collection-iterator-method)

Либо посложнее :

- [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1259516/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)
- [2](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1884-pattern-iterator)